# Javascript altering the absolute position of an html element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a new site, and as you'll see in the code below I have put two classes (logo & text) above a background fixed position image. I have put them over the top of the image using position absolute with left 50%, top 50% and transform: translate(-50%, -50%); this worked fine with no problems and was responsive the way I had hoped for.

But, as soon as I added my JS code (fade_effect) to the site it moved the position of the two elements (logo & text) slightly. Can someone please help me, have edited the code a number of times and researched it but cannot find a solution. I believe it may have something to do with the JS code section .offset() after what I've read, this seem like the part of the JS code that would be effecting the position of these elements. Please see code below:

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<body style="height: 2000px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">

<div class="img_slide">
  <h1 class="logo fade_effect">Logo Here</h1>
    <p class="text fade_effect">Welcome to My Site</p>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
/** Background image code BELOW **/
.img_slide {
height: 800px;
width: 100%;
background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, rgba(68, 0, 139, 0.7), rgba(47, 0, 120, 0.6) 10%, rgba(27, 57, 129, 0.5) 30%, rgba(41, 123, 192, 0.5) 50%, rgba(114, 240, 255, 0.6) 86%, rgba(84, 183, 249, 0.7)), url("http://www.strawberryproofing.co.uk/images/nature_large1.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0%, 0%, 50%, 50%;
background-attachment: scroll, fixed;
background-size: auto, cover;  
}
/** Background image code ABOVE **/


.logo {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 60px;
color: white;
padding: 25px;
border: 3px solid white;
/* position absolute - center */
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

.text {

color: white; 
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 25px;
padding: 10px;
/* position absolute - center */
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 70%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}



/** CSS code called by the JS .addClass **/

.fade_effect {

opacity: 0; 

}

.FadeIn {
-webkit-animation: slideIn 0.8s ease 0.3s forwards;
animation: slideIn 0.8s ease 0.3s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
0%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0;
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
}

}


@keyframes slideIn {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0;
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
}
} 

/** CSS code called by the JS .addClass **/
```

Javascript:

```
var $fade =  $(".fade_effect"); //Calling the class in HTML

$(window).scroll(function () { //Using the scroll global variable
$fade.each(function () {

    fadeMiddle = $(this).offset().top + (0.4 *$(this).height());
    windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    if (fadeMiddle < windowBottom) {
      $(this).addClass("FadeIn");
    }
    });
});

/* On Load: Trigger Scroll Once*/
$(window).scroll();
```

This can also be seen online via my CodePen page: https://codepen.io/billyfarroll/pen/qYWYYV

Comment: you are using bootstrap 4 , so why aren't you using flex  box. is there any specific reason for not using flex box

Comment: No if i'm honest there is no specific reason as to why I'm not using flexbox styling, I just wanted to work with the absolute position and see if that would work alongside my JS code I've used. But as I said, when I add the JS it moves the position of my .logo & .text classes from the center for whatever reason I don't know and am trying to figure out. If I used the display: flexbox, do you think this may be helpful on this scenario?

Comment: is this what you want ?                 https://codepen.io/__Deepanshu/pen/WJQezV?editors=1010

Comment: Yes, this is brilliant, haven't had chance to look at the code yet, what was it that you changed? Or what was it that was making my position alter? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't use position, as you already using the Bootstrap 4 which has its own inbuilt feature to align content vertically and horizontally center i.e **flexbox**. you should read about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <style>
            /** Background image code BELOW **/
            .img_slide {
                height: 800px;
                width: 100%;
                background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, rgba(68,
                    0, 139, 0.7), rgba(47, 0, 120, 0.6) 10%, rgba(27, 57, 129, 0.5) 30%, rgba(41, 123, 192, 0.5) 50%, rgba(114, 240, 255, 0.6) 86%, rgba(84, 183, 249, 0.7)), url("http://www.strawberryproofing.co.uk/images/nature_large1.png");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: 0%, 0%, 50%, 50%;
                background-attachment: scroll, fixed;
                background-size: auto, cover;
            }
            /** Background
            image code ABOVE **/
            .logocontainer {
                color: white;
                padding: 0 20px;
                border: 3px solid white;
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
            }
            .logo {
                font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-size: 60px;
                color: white;
                padding: 25px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .text {
                color: white;
                font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-size: 25px;
                padding: 10px;
                /* position absolute - center */
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                top: 70%;
                /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
            }
            /** CSS
            code called by the JS .addClass **/
            .fade_effect {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            .FadeIn {
                -webkit-animation: slideIn 0.8s ease 0.3s forwards;
                animation: slideIn 0.8s ease 0.3s forwards;
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 40px);
                    opacity: 0;
                }
                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
            @keyframes slideIn {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 40px);
                    opacity: 0;
                }
                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
            /** CSS code called by the JS .addClass **/
        </style>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 2000px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <div class="img_slide">
            <div class="logocontainer fade_effect">
                <h1 class="logo">
                    Logo Here
                </h1>
                <p class="text fade_effect">
                    Welcome to My Site
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var $fade = $(".fade_effect");
            //Calling the class in HTML 
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                //Using the scroll global variable
                $fade.each(function () {
                    fadeMiddle = $(this).offset().top + (0.4 * $(this).height());
                    windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
                    if (fadeMiddle < windowBottom) {
                        $(this).addClass("FadeIn");
                    }
                }
                          );
            }
                            );
            /* On Load: Trigger Scroll Once*/
            $(window).scroll();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, just wrap the logo and text elements in a div, and position it where you want.

```
<div class="logoContainer">
  <h1 class="logo fade_effect">Logo Here</h1>
  <p class="text fade_effect">Welcome to My Site</p>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.logoContainer {
  color: white;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
.logo {
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
.text {
  font-size: 25px;
 }
```

JSbin if you need it: http://jsbin.com/xerezohabo/edit?output

Comment: Hi Almatrass, have tried this way of css styling, although this does work and is responsive, it's doing the same as before, when I add the CSS class of .fade_effect (for the jS to work) it alters the position slightly and moves it for 50% left 50% top. As I said in the description of the query, I believe it may have something to do with the JS code I have used, but can't figure out which part of the code is doing this.